# Feed images 1by 1 from folder into function

Tags: image, matlab, loops, directory

I have an INPUT_IMAGE_CHECK_ALL function that takes image. In INPUT_IMAGE_CHECK_ALL there are 7 functions that image is passed to.

How do I feed images from folder 1 by 1 to the INPUT_IMAGE_CHECK_ALL function?

```
image = imread('6-Capmissing/capmissing-image078.jpg');

INPUT_IMAGE_CHECK_ALL(image);
```

INPUT_IMAGE_CHECK_ALL code:

```
function [  ] = INPUT_IMAGE_CHECK_ALL( image )

CHECK_FOR_CAP(image);
CHECK_FOR_NOLABEL(image);
CHECK_FOR_NOLABELPRINT(image);
CHECK_FOR_OVERFILLED(image);
CHECK_FOR_LABELNOTSTRAIGHT(image);
CHECK_FOR_UNDERFILLED(image);

end
```

Images that I want to feed into INPUT_IMAGE_CHECK_ALL are in folder "All" named image001 to image141.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know how the name of the images you want to read (*image001, image002, ...* from 1 to 141) the easiest way is to use a loop in which:

- build the names using the function [sprintf](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html)
- read the image whith the name you've build
- feed your function with the image data

A possible implementation could be

```
for img_idx=1:141
   img_name=sprintf('All/image%3.3d.jpg',img_idx)
   disp(['Reading ' img_name])
   the_image=imread(img_name);
   INPUT_IMAGE_CHECK_ALL(the_image);
end
```

In the above code:

- notice the `format` used in the call to `sprintf`: `%3.3d`: this allows padding with `0` the number in the buildoing of the filename, so that you can have *001*, *002*, ... *013* and so on
- if the folder `All` in which your images are stored is not in the MatlLab `path` you have to specify the folder in building the filename
- I've used `the_image` as name of the variable in which to store the data of the image because `image` (the varaible you are using) is a MatLab function.
- the call to the `disp` function is used only to print on the CommandWindow a message about what the script is dooing (which image is processing); you can remove it

If the folder `All` only the images you you want to process, another possibility could be to get the list of images using the function [dir](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) to get the filenames of the

The function `dir` returns a `struct` in which the information about the files are stored.

In this case you have to loop over the list returned by `dir`

```
% Get the filenames of all the images in the folder "All"
img_list=dir('All/image*.jpg')
% Loops over the list of images
for img_idx=1:length(img_list)
   img_name=['All/' img_list(img_idx).name]
   disp(['Reading ' img_name])
   the_image=imread(img_name)
   INPUT_IMAGE_CHECK_ALL(the_image);
end
```

Hope this helps,

Qapla'

Comment: I cant tell you enought how usefull that was! thank you!